# Error on class SignatureHandler (The type or namespace SignatureHandler could not be found) : GroupDocs

Tags: groupdocs

I am working on a project in which we are using groupdocs, I recently updated the version to 20.1 from 19.8, and now I am getting the following error

> CS0246 C# The type or namespace name could not be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

the error is coming on the following line of code

```
private static SignatureHandler SignatureHandler;
```

I didn't changed any code just changed the version of groupdocs signature

when i studied the release note I found out the legacy api which contains handler has been removed in the same version (20.1) and hence, the following namespace is also throwing error

```
GroupDocs.Signature.Legacy.Handler;
```

here is the release of groupdocs signature 20.1

[release note](https://docs.groupdocs.com/signature/net/groupdocs-signature-for-net-20-1-release-notes/)

what can be the fixes for me?

Answer (score 0):

In API [v20.1](https://docs.groupdocs.com/signature/net/groupdocs-signature-for-net-20-1-release-notes/), we've removed the legacy API support from the product.

> what can be the fixes for me?

Below is the new code style:

```
using (Signature signature = new Signature("sample.pdf"))
{
    TextSignOptions options = new TextSignOptions("John Smith")
    {
        // locate signature
        Left = 100, Top = 100, Width = 100, Height = 30,
        // set Text color and Font
        ForeColor = Color.Red,
        Font = new SignatureFont { Size = 12, FamilyName = "Comic Sans MS" }
    };
    // sign document to file
    signature.Sign("signed.pdf", options);
}
```

`SignatureHandler` is no longer supported. Please have a look at these [migration notes](https://docs.groupdocs.com/signature/net/migration-notes/) for more insights.